# How to select only certain area for object detection in YOLO? (using ROS package)

Tags: python, opencv, object-detection, ros, yolo

I need to count only objects in certain region on the image feed - the area is in a shape of a triangle. I am using darknet ROS package for object detection. 
I see two ways - either 1. filter the detection area or 2. based on the resulting bounding boxes only count if in valid region.

Since I am using a ROS package (if anyone is familiar with ROS), should I build a new node or change the original source?

Comment: opencv allows to use subimages, but regarding a triangle (or other polygon) is handles best by postprocessing the detected objects. If want a speedup and you can ignore bigger image parts, you can use subimages and reducr the grid size in yolo v3

Comment: Unless performance really is a problem, build a new node rather than changing source.

Comment: By performance I mean if you need callbacks to arrive faster.

Comment: this will never be a good idea but what if you use two models ? one to detect the area and then detect the objects in that area with the yolo ?!